# How do I "Change the Value of a Setting Between Application Sessions" in a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, settings, application-settings

The MSDN web [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx#settingscs_topic4) makes it sound easy to change application settings by hand.  I can't find the file though.  I can find the file in my development path, but I have no idea if that is the path the application is actually running in.  I set a DB connection setting in "settings.settings" and now I want to change it on my machine.  I understand that for my Foo.exe there is a Foo.exe.config, but I can't find it.

Where is it? How do I find it?

Comment: I actually found it when I installed on a different machine but I couldn't tell you why it is here and if this is a cache or the "real" application file: C:\Documents and Settings\laqlu\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\9MNP3TX3.N7R\H7MCGW2O.1GY\drev..tion_21d5cfff11fb53be_0001.0000_2da6fd46b18765ae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the section "Settings File Locations" in the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx

The application-level settings and default user-level settings will be stored in `yourProgram.exe.config` in the same directory as the executable. The user-level settings are stored in `user.config` in a location which differs according to the deployment method.

The path you mention in `C:\Documents and Settings\laqlu\Local Settings\Apps\...` is not a cached file, it is the actual user-level settings file. Changing its content will affect your program.